# Why is MVC4 bundling and minification making my files bigger?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization

I am implementing the bundling and minification support in MVC4 and it appears as though it is making my javascript files bigger than if they weren't bundled/minified.  I am using the latest build available in nuget (pre-release option on).  I have the following bundle set up in my RegisterBundles class.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/baseJS").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.pjax.js",
                    "~/Scripts/kendo/2012.1.515/js/kendo.all.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.jstree.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                    "~/RIS.Scripts/PostJson.js"));
```

And I am loading it into my _Layout.cshtml using

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/baseJS")
```

When I add up the bytes received in Fiddler for these scripts in debug mode I get the following

```
Name                        Size(bytes)
jquery                      98013
jquery cookie               1455
jquery ui                   124704
bootstrap                   52378
pjax                        8138
kendo.all                   219751
jstree                      55045
unobtrusive-ajax            2492
validate                    13323
validate-unobtrusive        5138
postjson                    634

Total                       581071
```

And when I run it on my production server I get the following from fiddler for the entire js bundle.

```
Bytes Received:  999,396
```

What is going on here?  Most of the files are minified to some extent, but it shouldn't almost double the size of my payload.

Additional details-
    When I download the js files off my local dev box (fiddler reported size 379kb) and the server (fiddler reported size 999kb) and put them in kdiff they are binary identical.  When I look in Chrome's developer tools network tab, the local server downloads 379kb, but the 'Parser' value is 975kb.  What is this parser value.  Could it be that there is some IIS compression setting that is not set in my server but is on my local IIS server?  The only difference I note is the fact that the IIS Express I am running on my dev machine is 8.0 where the server is IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most likely what you are seeing here is some of the debug/release 'magic' that comes from the `FileExtensionReplacementList`.

Let's take jQuery for example.  Typically in your scripts folder you will see two copies of each file, i.e. `jquery-1.6.2.js` and `jquery-1.6.2.min.js`.

By default optimization will use the `min.js` version when `debug=false`, and use the regular `jquery-1.6.2.js` when `debug=true`, since typically that makes debugging easier (no bundling and no minification of the bundle).

This file selection 'magic' is controlled via the `FileExtensionReplacementList` on `BundleCollection`.

In the next release (RTM), there will be a bit more granularity in this list, as typically developers will want to target when these are should be used, i.e.

```
list.Add("min", OptimizationMode.WhenEnabled);
list.Add("debug", OptimizationMode.WhenDisabled);
```

Comment: Note: Hao is the lead developer on bundling/minification for ASP.NET

Comment: If I understand the answer correctly I guess my question then is why is Jquery's minification tighter than ASP.net's?

Answer (score 4):

You have the bundling option working, but the minification is done by an `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true` setting and some "transform" options that you've haven't engaged. See CssMinify and JsMinify.

Something along the lines of:

```
        var b1 =new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-1.*");

        b1.Transforms.Add(new JsMinify());

        bundles.Add(b1);
```

- and -

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Comment: I'll try this first thing in the morning....but why would it make it bigger?  That is the part that is really confusing me.

Comment: You are correct about the b1.transforms.Add(new JsMinify()); that fixes my problem and the total download is less than the sum of the un-minified files.  The EnableOptimizations = true; just turns debugging off and bundles and minifies everything on your local dev box like it would on the server.

Comment: Ok when I ran this on my dev box with EnableOptimizations = true; it bundled and minified the js file to 388,447 bytes which is about what I would expect.  When I deploy it to my server with no code changes it is 999,350 bytes.  How can this be?

Comment: From my understanding the internal logic used to bundle and such takes into account a debug verses a release build. It will choose different files based on this state. An example might be a .min.js for release, but the plain version for debug.

Comment: continuing ... 

Skipping back to your question about "why would it make it bigger", is most-likely because the bundler adds separation comments to help in debugging and I hope some sort of isolation logic to reduce any conflicts between the scripts. I haven't dug that deep yet, but that is how I "see it".Remember it is still only RC code and it might have a few bugs.

Comment: If you get a chance read the comments that I added to the original question at the end.  I'm starting to wonder if it doesn't have somehting to do with IIS 7.5 vs. IIS 8.

Comment: As per http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification, it seems EnableOptimizations sets both and overrides the debug or release logic to determine to enable both bundling/minification